# Функции при обработке строк в python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Хочу разбить скрипт для скачивания картинок на функции, чтобы проще было применять для разных сайтов. Но что-то идёт не так.
Вот так всё работает:

```
   req = urllib.request.Request(url, data=None, headers=agent)
   remotefile = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
   remotedata = remotefile.readlines()
   remotefile.close()     
   for line in remotedata:
       line = line.decode('utf-8')
       if '<a id="p' in line:
           line = line.replace('amp;', '')
           links = re.split('["+]', line)
           links = links[3]
           print('Download url:', links)
           req = urllib.request.Request(links, data=None, headers=agent)
           remotefile2 = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
           remotedata2 = remotefile2.readlines()
           remotefile2.close
           for line in remotedata2:
               line = line.decode('utf-8')
               if '<li><a href="javascript:;" onclick="$(' in line:
                   line = re.split("'", line)
                   line = line[7]
                   print('Download image:', line)
                   req = urllib.request.Request(line, data=None,
                                                headers=agent)
                   link = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
                   image_name = os.path.basename(line)
                   image_name = directory + image_name
                   image = link.read()
                   myimage = open(image_name, 'wb')
                   myimage.write(image)
                   myimage.close()
                   link.close()
```

Когда делаю так, скачивает одно изображение и останавливается:

```
   req = urllib.request.Request(url, data=None, headers=agent)
   remotefile = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
   remotedata = remotefile.readlines()
   remotefile.close()
   link = gelbsplit(remotedata)
   print('Download url:', link)
   req = urllib.request.Request(link, data=None, headers=agent)
   remotefile = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
   remotedata = remotefile.readlines()
   remotefile.close
   link = gelbsplit(remotedata)
   print('Download image:', link)
   req = urllib.request.Request(link, data=None,
                                headers=agent)
   remoteimg = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
   image_name = os.path.basename(link)
   image_name = directory + image_name
   image = remoteimg.read()
   myimage = open(image_name, 'wb')
   myimage.write(image)
   myimage.close()
   remoteimg.close()

def gelbsplit(remotedata):
   for line in remotedata:
       line = line.decode('utf-8')
       if '<a id="p' in line:
           line = line.replace('amp;', '')
           line = re.split('["+]', line)
           line = line[3]
           return line
       elif '<li><a href="javascript:;" onclick="$(' in line:
           line = re.split("'", line)
           line = line[7]
           return line
```

Comment: Складывается впечатление, что попутно Вы пытаетесь изобрести `requests` и `bs4`. Можете запостить ссылку на страницу, откуда пытаетесь качать и более подробно описать результат, которого хотите добиться? Почему-то кажется, что все это реализуется гораздо проще

Comment: @Namerek Я тоже уверен, что это реализуется гораздо проще, но я не знаю как, потому что учу python первый месяц. :) Верхний скрипт скачивает все картинки со страницы на гелбуру. Например: https://gelbooru.com/index.php?page=post&s=list&tags=rating%3asafe Для других подобных сайтов отличается только метод поиска нужных строк и получения из них ссылок. Что я пытался оформить функцией, но у меня не получается.

Comment: Начало скрирпта отсутствует, оно одинаково в обоих случаях.

Comment: Спрошу на всякий случай, Вы не из России пытаетесь спарсить этот сайт, просто он заблокирован РКН. Если да, то трафик скрипта придется проксировать еще до кучи

Comment: @Namerek
С этим всё в порядке. Кстати, Request там для эксперемента просто. С функцией, что-то рабочее получилось. По уродски конечно, но, вроде работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pip install bs4 fake_useragent requests tqdm`

*на первом запуске fake_useragent матюгнется*

```py
from requests import Session, Response
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
from bs4.element import Tag
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from pathlib import Path
from tqdm import tqdm


s = Session()
ua = UserAgent()
s.headers.update(
    {
        'User-Agent': ua.firefox
    }
)

url = 'https://gelbooru.com/index.php?page=post&s=list&tags=rating%3asafe'

response = s.get(url)

soup = Soup(response.content, 'html.parser')


def snippet_parse(snpi: Tag):
    a = snpi.find('a')
    item_id = a.get('id')
    link = a.get('href')

    preview_link = None
    if isinstance(img := a.find('img'), Tag):
        preview_link = img.get('src')

    return item_id, link, preview_link


def parse_page(page_url: str) -> Response:
    page_response = s.get(
        page_url
    )
    page_soup = Soup(page_response.content, 'html.parser')

    img_tag = page_soup.find('img', class_="fit-width")
    return s.get(
        img_tag.get('src')
    )


prewievs = Path('./storage/prewievs')
prewievs.mkdir(exist_ok=True, parents=True)

images = Path('./storage/images')
images.mkdir(exist_ok=True, parents=True)

bar = tqdm()


for _item_id, _link, _preview_link in map(
        snippet_parse,
        soup.find_all('article', class_="thumbnail-preview")
):
    file = prewievs.joinpath(f'{_item_id}_pre.jpg')
    response = s.get(_preview_link)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        file.write_bytes(response.content)
    
    if (img_response := parse_page(_link)).status_code == 200:
        img_file = images.joinpath(f'{_item_id}.jpg')
        img_file.write_bytes(
            img_response.content
        )
    bar.update()
```

Comment: Спасибо, у меня оно уже заработало. Думаю, постить сюда моё поделие не имеет смысла. Мне оно нужно больше для учебных целей и спортивного интереса - сделать что-то работающее, используя только стандартную библиотеку. Но за ответ спасибо!

Comment: @Ilya, Ну на старте может и интересно без сторонних библиотек, но потом становится жалко времени на выдумывание велосипеда. Удачи